# Extending Django User model with django-allauth

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-authentication

I'm using django-allauth and I want to be able to add new field to my User model.
What's the best way to do this as of you ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use userena. But I am sure that it will look almost the same ;)

```
class UserProfile(UserenaBaseProfile):

        user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
        city = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
```

in settings.py:

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'accounts.UserProfile'
```

Answer (score 3):

See the docs [Storing additional information about users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users), Make a model with `OneToOneField` relation to `User`.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # This field is required.
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    # Other fields here
    accepted_eula = models.BooleanField()
    favorite_animal = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="Dragons.")
```